# How to change the response messages in Tymon JWT package laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I want to change response messages in the Tymon JWT package. For example, while fetching the data with  Invalid token I am getting this response

```
 "message": "Invalid token.",
"exception": "Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenInvalidException",
```

I need o change this from above response to below response

```
 "errors": "Invalid token.",
"exception": "Tymon\\JWTAuth\\Exceptions\\TokenInvalidException",
```

controller code

```
        try {
             $assign = AssignmentResource::collection(DB::table('assignments')->whereIn('assignments.academic_id',$ids)
            ->whereIn('assignments.batch',$batch)
            ->whereIn('assignments.course',$classid)->get());

            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

                return response()->json(['success' => false,'errors' => $e,'status' => 404] );



            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

                return response()->json(['success' => false,'errors' =>$e,'status' => 404] ); 

            } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

                return response()->json(['success' => false,'errors' =>$e,'status' => 404] );

            }
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the laravel Exceptions.

inside  `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` you can customize your message.

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($request->is('api/*') || $request->expectsJson() || $request->is('webhook/*')) {
            if ($exception instanceof Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidExceptio) {

                return [
                    'errors' => $exception->getMessage(),
                    'exception' => 'your message'

                ];

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `$exception` must be `instanceof` `Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException` not `Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException`.

Comment: @matheenulla what kind of error you are getting? what is your route in url?

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I am not getting any response it is completely blank. I am testing in postman

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz thank you very very much  bro it is working fine. before in your code some spelling mistake was there so it was not taking

Answer (score 1):

If you see [Exception Handling](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/exception-handling/) page of Tymon JWT Auth, then it is coming soon:

One way you can achieve this is like using `try..catch`:

```
  try {

    // Your code here.

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

    // return your response.

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

     // return your response.

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

     // return your response.

    }
```

Comment: In the controller I need to use?

Comment: Yes. Use it where you are using JWT related code. So whenever Exception occurred, you need to send your appropriate response.

Comment: ok thank you I am using this now if I got some error I will tell you

Comment: I am getting the same response

Comment: hey, I just added that code which you have told me. I am getting the same response you can check I have edited the question